# Не работает обработка элементов списка

Tags: python

Нужно подсчитать сумму положительных и произведение отрицательных элементов списка. Вывести элементы, которые соответствуют критериям отбора.
Не работает обработка. Не знаю что делать.

Ошибка:

```
File "main.py", line 12, in <module>                                                                                         
    if eval(Values[i]) > 0:                                                                                                    
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Сам код:

```
Values = []
Desired_values = []

Amount = 0
Composition = 1

for i in range(1, 11):
    print('Введите {number} элемент списка: '.format(number = i))
    Values.append(input())

for i in range(1, 11):
    if eval(Values[i]) > 0:
        Amount += eval(Values[i])
        Desired_values.append(Values[i])
    elif eval(Values[i]) < 0:
        Composition *= eval(Values[i])
        Desired_values.append(Values[i])

print()
print('Список состоит из таких элементов: ')
print(Values)
print()
print('Значения, которые подходят по критериям: ')
print(Desired_values)
print()
print('Сумма положительный элементов: ' & str(Amount))
print('Произведение отрицательных элементов: ' & str(Composition))
```

Comment: ну а зачем надо было использовать eval-функцию? int недостаточно разве?

Comment: Да, достаточно. Изменилa input() на int(input())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь, дело в том что индекс массива начинается с 0 и до 10, а вы пытаетесь вынуть элемент с индексом 11.

```
Values = []
Desired_values = []

Amount = 0
Composition = 1

for i in range(1, 11):
    print('Введите {number} элемент списка: '.format(number = i))
    Values.append(input())

for i in range(10):
    if eval(Values[i]) > 0:
        Amount += eval(Values[i])
        Desired_values.append(Values[i])
    elif eval(Values[i]) < 0:
        Composition *= eval(Values[i])
        Desired_values.append(Values[i])

print()
print('Список состоит из таких элементов: ')
print(Values)
print()
print('Значения, которые подходят по критериям: ')
print(Desired_values)
print()
print('Сумма положительный элементов: ', Amount)
print('Произведение отрицательных элементов: ', Composition)
```